# React-medium-Editor Text Not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-medium-editor (https://github.com/wangzuo/react-medium-editor) and text in Editor never goes blank

```
  handleChange=(text)=>{
    this.setState({text: text});
  }

 Submit(){
 this.setState({text: ''});
 }


 render(){
 return(
   <div>
   <Editor
    text={this.state.text}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={{placeholder: {text: "Write your response here"},
             toolbar: {buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
     }}} />
    <button onClick={this.Submit.bind(this)}></button>
    </div>
    )
}
```

when i click on button this.setState is setting up value of Text to blank but Editor text never goes to blank.

How i can make Editor value blank by setting up state.

Answer (score 0):

Make the last commit or show the Editor here. I can't test it.
(Or specify in which branch this happens)

Comment: help me.. if you can